# Formatting Chemfig inside of table

Tags: tables, chemfig

I am trying to create a list of organic compounds as part of a table. However, when I add the chemfig elements into the table they touch the top and bottom of the cell which is undesirable. Additionally, longer chains extend past the width of the cell. Any ideas?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{0.2\textwidth}|c|} 
\hline
IUPAC Name & Formula &  Line Diagram & Molar Mass ($\frac{g}{mol}$)  \\ 
\hhline{|====|}
Methanol   & $CH_3OH_{(g)}$  &   \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)}     &     32.04        \\ 
\hline
Ethanol    &  $C_2H_5OH_{(g)}$       &    \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)}     &     46.07        \\ 
\hline
2-methylpropan-1-ol           &  $C_4H_9OH_{(g)}$       &   SOON      &      74.12       \\
\hline
Butan-1-ol           &    $C_4H_9OH_{(g)}$     &    \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)}     &      74.12       \\
\hline
3-methylbutan-1-ol           &   $C_5H_{11}OH_{(g)}$      &   SOON      &     88.15        \\
\hline
Pentan-1-ol           &     $C_5H_{11}OH_{(g)}$    &   \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)}     &       88.15      \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table with chemfig]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't fix the chemistry pictures. Instead, fix the horizontal lines, i.e., replace the basic `\hline` macro with the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package to get well-spaced horizontal rules. Specifically, I suggest you replace the interior `\hline` directives with `\addlinespace[3mm]` throughout. Whitespace can be every bit a visual barrier as solid lines. Oh, and get rid of the vertical lines: They're not needed, and they won't be missed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{chemfig}  % for \chemfig macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{mhchem}   % for \ce macro
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for \unit macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c c c @{}} 
\toprule
IUPAC Name & Formula &  Line Diagram & Molar Mass \\
& & & (\unit[per-mode=symbol]{\gram\per\mol})  \\ 
\midrule
Methanol    & \ce{CH3OH_{(g)}}   & \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)} & 32.04 \\ 
\addlinespace[3mm]
Ethanol     & \ce{C2H5OH_{(g)}}  & \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)} & 46.07 \\ 
\addlinespace[3mm]
2-methylpropan-1-ol & \ce{C4H9OH_{(g)}} & SOON & 74.12 \\
\midrule
Butan-1-ol  & \ce{C4H9OH_{(g)}}  & \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)} & 74.12 \\
\addlinespace[3mm]
3-methylbutan-1-ol & \ce{C5H11OH_{(g)}} & SOON & 88.15 \\
\addlinespace[3mm]
Pentan-1-ol & \ce{C5H11OH_{(g)}} & \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)} & 88.15 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would make a few changes:

- Rotate the table to render it vertically and make more space for the figures;
  using `sidewaystable` env. is probably the most convenient way
- Change the fixed column p{} to a regular one, s.a. 'l'
- Get rid of vertical bars
- Optionally, add custom rules from `booktabs`.

Above changes improve the table but some figures might still be too close.

If you decide on `booktabs` and insert horizontal lines between each row, the lines add small gaps whose sizes are stored in `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`. Below is the code demonstrating this approach

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\setlength\aboverulesep{4pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{4pt}


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c l c c} 
    \toprule
    IUPAC Name
    & Formula
    & Line Diagram
    & Molar Mass ($\frac{g}{mol}$) \\ 
    \midrule
    Methanol
    & $CH_3OH_{(g)}$ 
    & \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)}
    & 32.04 \\
    \midrule
    Ethanol
    & $C_2H_5OH_{(g)}$ 
    & \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)}
    & 46.07 \\ 
    \midrule
    2-methylpropan-1-ol 
    & $C_4H_9OH_{(g)}$  
    & SOON    
    & 74.12 \\
    \midrule
    Butan-1-ol    
    & $C_4H_9OH_{(g)}$
    & \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
      -C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
      -C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)}  
    & 74.12 \\
    \midrule
    3-methylbutan-1-ol       
    & $C_5H_{11}OH_{(g)}$     
    & SOON
    & 88.15 \\
    \midrule
    Pentan-1-ol 
    & $C_5H_{11}OH_{(g)}$   
    & \chemfig{
      H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
      -C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
      -C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
      -O(-[6]H)}
    & 88.15 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One the other hand, you could also force top and bottom spacing in cells via `cellspace` package. These are controlled by another two length names from the package: `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit` (see the code below). The table will apply the minimum gaps to the `Sx` column, where `x` can be `l`, `c`, `r`, `p{}` etc. depending on horizontal alignment and width.

The example based on `cellspaces`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{cellspace}

\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c Sl c c} 
    \hline
    IUPAC Name
    & Formula
    & Line Diagram
    & Molar Mass ($\frac{g}{mol}$) \\ 
    \hline
    Methanol
    & $CH_3OH_{(g)}$ 
    & \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)}
    & 32.04 \\
    Ethanol
    & $C_2H_5OH_{(g)}$ 
    & \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)}
    & 46.07 \\ 
    2-methylpropan-1-ol 
    & $C_4H_9OH_{(g)}$  
    & SOON    
    & 74.12 \\
    Butan-1-ol    
    & $C_4H_9OH_{(g)}$
    & \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
      -C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
      -C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O(-[6]H)}  
    & 74.12 \\
    3-methylbutan-1-ol       
    & $C_5H_{11}OH_{(g)}$     
    & SOON
    & 88.15 \\
    Pentan-1-ol 
    & $C_5H_{11}OH_{(g)}$   
    & \chemfig{
      H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
      -C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
      -C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)
      -O(-[6]H)}
    & 88.15 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]